# Array to Object in kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I am looking for method to convert array into ojbect in kohana 
 I got this

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/arr#to_object

But this method does not work in kohana 3.1. 
What is new alternative for this function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it manually using PHP's [`type casting`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) (There is lower header with Type casting):

```
$array = array('a' => 'c', 'b' => 'd');
$obj = (object)$array;

echo $obj->a; // c
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single-dimensional array, just cast it to `object` using `$obj = (object)$array;`

Answer (score 0):

You can override Arr class.

1. Create file APPPATH/classes/arr.php:
2. Add new method:

   ```
   class Arr extends Kohana_Arr {

   public static function to_object(array $array, $class = 'stdClass')
   {
           $object = new $class;
           foreach ($array as $key => $value)
           {
                   if (is_array($value))
                   {
                   // Convert the array to an object
                           $value = arr::to_object($value, $class);
                   }
                   // Add the value to the object
                   $object->{$key} = $value;
           }
           return $object;
   }
   ```

   }